# React-datepicker corruption - days of the week

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

[image: corruption]

Has anyone seen this kind of corruption when using the react-datepicker? I have the datepicker within a  react component. Here's the code I have. This started happening after I update rect-datepicker from 0.25.0 to 0.39.0 due to errors with v25. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

            <Col md={2}>
              <DatePicker
                minDate={this.state.minFilterDateTime}
                maxDate={this.state.maxFilterDateTime}
                onChange={this._changeFilterFromDateTime}
                selected={this.state.filterFromDateTime} />
            </Col>
```

Comment: check this out !
https://github.com/Abolfazl2647/rn-datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS class for the day names have changed between those versions, so you must  also update your `react-datepicker` CSS file (or reference), for example

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datepicker/0.39.0/react-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Edit**

The block of CSS that tells the new `react-datepicker__day-name` class to `display: inline-block`:

```
.react-datepicker__day-name,
.react-datepicker__day {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.7rem;
    line-height: 1.7rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.166rem;
}
```

Comment: I completely missed that part of it, so I went and add the css from the library, but unfortunately, that still didn't work. I've updated my question with how I imported the css and datepicker. thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the important part of the CSS changes. Make sure your CSS file looks like that. A working example can be found here (v0.37, but mostly the same as v0.39): https://codepen.io/jochenberger/pen/xRpQOK

Comment: Thanks. The reason why it wasn't working for me after the import is that there's a global css that was created by the previous developer that I wasn't aware of.